# Assigning values to a table record

Tags: collections, plsql, oracle10g

I tried the below code and wanted to see output of the assigned record 
but it gives nothing.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_obj as object(
  book_name varchar2(20),
  ISBN      number,
  author    varchar2(20)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_table as table of t_obj;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_ret_tab 
   RETURN t_table
IS
   vl_table   t_table := t_table ();
BEGIN
   FOR j IN 1 .. vl_table.COUNT
   LOOP
      vl_table.EXTEND;
      vl_table (vl_table.LAST) :=
         t_obj ('oracle programming', 2132, 'steven feurestein');

   END LOOP;
   return vl_table;
END;
```

Comment: Would vl_table.COUNT not be 0 or even NULL as it is newly created without any initial elements?

Answer (score 0):

As vl_table.COUNT is 0, try the following:

```
create or replace FUNCTION fun_ret_tab 
   RETURN t_table
IS
   vl_table   t_table := t_table ();
BEGIN
   -- Start Loop at 0
   FOR j IN 0 .. vl_table.COUNT
   LOOP
      vl_table.EXTEND;
      vl_table (vl_table.LAST) :=
         t_obj ('oracle programming', 2132, 'steven feurestein');

END LOOP;
   return vl_table;
END;
```